# SQL Server trigger to other SQL Server (both 2005)

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

Is it possible to trigger to another SQL Server?

Say data is inserted into `[server1].[database].[tablename]`, I want it to also insert into `[server2].[database].[tablename]`. Is that possible?

How do I set it up like that? I especially need to know about granting user permissions.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean [server1].[database].[dbo].[tablename] - you missed a bit ;)

Comment: Setting up the action itself and setting up the necessary permissions are two very different problems. I really think you should split your question. And try searching for ready answers first, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [server2] to sys.servers table on [server1]. Then you'll able to query from one server to another